# Drop down menu always displays 1st option after page processing instead of processed option

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu works fine query-wise but with 2 issues:

1-When I select an option and hit the submit button, the query comes back fine but instead of the drop down menu displaying the processed option, it's actually always displaying the 1st option regardless of the processed option.

2-When I enter my page, no data is displayed until I pick up an option from the drop down menu and hit submit. I would like the page to process the 1st option by default when I enter it the first time.

```
<form action="http://localhost/xampp/mydomain.com/?page_id=2283" method='post'>
<select name="selected_date">
    <option value="2012-05-01">01.05.2012</option>
    <option value="2012-04-01">01.04.2012</option>
    <option value="2012-03-01">01.03.2012</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" VALUE="Go"/>
    </form>

$date=$_POST['selected_date'];

$query = " SELECT * from table1 WHERE
 `drop_date` > '$date' AND
 `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
```

Any help is welcome ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, fought hard on this one, I am going to answer my own question :

```
<?php
$date=$_POST['selected_date']; //retrieves submitted option
?>

<form action="file.php" method='post'> As of :
<select name="selected_date">
<option value="2012-05-01" <?php if ( $date == '2012-05-01' ) {echo " selected";}?> >01.05.2012</option>
<option value="2012-04-01" <?php if ( $date == '2012-04-01' ) {echo " selected";}?> >01.04.2012</option>
<option value="2012-03-01" <?php if ( $date == '2012-03-01' ) {echo " selected";}?> >01.03.2012</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" VALUE="Get Data"/>
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['selected_date'])
$date=$_POST['selected_date'];
else
$date="2012-05-01"; // assigns a default option to be processed until user submits another one (to avoid empty feedback on 1st page load)
?> //
```

Using BelgianAlien's answer I ended up adding the first code that retrieves the submitted option so it can be recognized in the following options' IF statement

I have also added the last code lines that enable a default option to be processed on first page load avoiding an empty feedback from the server.

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that the visitor is redirected back to the same page when they hit the "Go" button after selecting a date. To have their selection show up in the drop down, you would have to read their selection first before the  element.

```
    <select name="selected_date">
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['selected_date'])){
          $selected_date = $_POST['selected_date'];
          echo "
            <option selected value=\"".$selected_date."\">".$selected_date."</option>
          "; 
        }
      ?>
      <option value="2012-05-01">01.05.2012</option>
      <option value="2012-04-01">01.04.2012</option>
      <option value="2012-03-01">01.03.2012</option>
    </select>
```

Essentially all it does is it checks to see if the form was posted and grabs the selected date, adds an option to your select element with that date as a value an has it selected so it is selected in the dropdown when the page loads.

As far as your issue with the page not showing ANY selections on the first page load, I believe your problem is that none of the options in your select element have a "selected" attribute.

I hope this helps you out... keep us posted!

BelgianAlien.

Comment: Hi BelgianAlien, your assumption is right, visitor is redirected to the same page upon selecting a date. Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work for me. your php code, indeed, adds the latest processed option on the top of the other options but without showing it as selected. it just kept showing the 1st option. As for the no data is displayed on initial page load, adding selected attribute didn't make any difference. tricky one....